# Programmable current-limit/e-fuse (+current monitoring?)

Tags: current-limiting, power-management, efuse

**Short version:**

How best to make either a current limiting circuit or an e-fuse (both options are fine to me) so that I can set the limit from software (and not through a fixed resistor as usual)?

Voltage: 24 V (bonus: working also at 48 V)

Current limit: covering at least the 0.5-3 A range (bonus: up to 5 A or even a bit more)

Available communications methods: I2C (small preference), SPI, UART, GPIO, (USB, PCIe, Ethernet). Analog in/out possible through I2C ADC/DAC.

**Long version:**

I'm working on the main PCB for a robot, with many connectors providing power and various data to external components (some common to all robots, some for which there are a few variations, some that we integrate for specific clients, and some that are mounted by the client himself).

Currently, we provide 24 V on each connector, with simple, fixed fuses. For now, the fuses are rather low (1-3 A) and the total amount of connectors is low enough that it is unlikely (but not impossible) to reach the maximum current of the supply.

I would like to add far more connectors, and allow more high power connectors (at least 3 A, if I can provide 5 A or even 10 A it's even better).

The issue is that it isn't practical to size the power supply such that it can accommodate the maximum current of all connectors at the same time (knowing that in practice most of them are far bellow their limits).

So I would like to be able to limit, in software, the current for each connector in order to:

- ensure that each connector gets some allocated current (a most) and that the total remains within the capability of the supply
- in case of a fault, I don't blow the fuse (hard to access): I would like either to limit the current to the maximum value as in a lab supply) or to cut the supply (like an e-fuse)

Monitoring the current is a plus.

The high level software (on a Jetson SoM) should be able to set the limits. I do NOT want however to rely on it to do the monitoring and to cut the output in case of over-current. Ideally, I would like the cutting to be done on a "hardware" level, or if too complicated on a micro-controller level.

The requirements:

- adjustable current limit, covering at least the range 0.5-3 A. Range 0-5 A (or even 0-10 A) would be even better.
- at least 4 different current limits (0.5 A, 3 A, and 2 somewhere in between), a 0.5 A step or finer would be ideal.
- in case of over current, either limiting current, or opening a switch (like an e-fuse)
- accuracy: <10% (bonus if <5%, no big interest in going lower)
- if e-fuse like: allowing some inrush handling (delay or current limiting)
- if e-fuse like: allowing either automatic restart (or from logic signal)
- speed: not well defined yet. Faster than a thermal fuse. (if e-fuse like, then slow enough to avoid problem with inrush current)
- voltage: 24 V (bonus if also working with 48 V)
- voltages rails available: 1.8 V, 3.3 V, 5 V, 12 V, -12 V, 24 V, 48 V
- bonus: including current monitoring (so I can get a reading from the Jetson, for example through I2C). If not included, I will probably add it separately
- it is possible to locate 4 connectors near to each other (to share components). I expect to use this solution on 8-20 connectors in total (depending mainly on the PCB space required)

Priorities:

1. reliability
2. PCB space
3. ease of design
4. cost : very little impact, 20$+ per current limiter is no issue

**Current ideas:**

1. Existing e-fuse ICs (like [TPS1663x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps1663.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1703681353839&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftps1663) or many others). The problem is that all those I found with adjustable current limit use a resistor to set the current limit. So this would require either using a programmable resistor/potentiometer/rheostat IC (ex: [MCP4XXX](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22107B.pdf)), or to build a simple one by switching a few resistors using MOSFETs.
2. Doing everything in analog: a small shunt resistor measures current, then we amplify it with an opamp (this voltage can also be measured with an ADC for monitoring), then a comparatr (or second opamp in same package) compares the current measurement with a reference voltage generated by a DAC. The output of the comparator drives a switch. Nothing exotic this time, but lots of components.

Do you have any better/simpler ideas?

Comment: [TPS2359](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS2359) is described as having ``I2C Programmable Fault Times and Current Limits``. However, that device is for _Systems Using 12 V and 3.3 V_. Perhaps another TI [eFuses & hot swap controllers](https://www.ti.com/power-management/power-switches/efuse-hotswap-controllers/products.html) would have suitable voltage rail support.

Comment: Good try. Sadly there seem to be none in the list for voltages 24V or more that enable to set the threshold through I2C (some allow I2C monitoring)

Answer (score 1):

A current sensor IC read by a small dedicated microcontroller that can trip a relay at a user-defined limit and do the I2C, inrush delay, etc is probably your best bet.  If you want current limiting, your supply would have to be adjustable with an external signal.

Comment: Indeed, it's a rather simple solution (excepted that I will have to ensure the micro-controller is programmable from the Jetson in case we detect some bug). It will require some thinking about how best to read the current (either though I2C sensors, or the analog way through the internal ADC), specially as I will probably need to group many such sensors on the same micro-controler to keep this solution practical. Current limiting is not needed if I can cut at over-current + control inrush. If I can't find a simple full hardware solution, this will do the job.

Comment: There are a few current sensors with I2C interface but most are ratiometric (e.g. 100mV/A), so a dedicated ADC channel for each connector is necessary. This approach shouldn't end up being too expensive or complex.